# How to set bpy.context.window.scene in the right context?

Tags: python, rendering, scene

I would like to set the active scene with bpy.context.window.scene = my_scene

Now the problem is that normally this works if you are in the right context, the problem (in my specific case) is inside a function that is executed immediately after `bpy.ops.render.render ('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`
immediately after the end of the render I get:

```
for s in bpy.data.scenes:
     if s == my_scene:
         context.window.scene = s
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'scene'

so I guess currently the context has changed to that of rendering, am I wrong?

How can I solve this?

Comment: The issue here is `context.window is None`  Similar to issue the other day in my deleted answer re closing render preview window. It seems somewhere the context gets "lost".  Try `windows = set(context.window_manager.windows[:])` before and after opening the render window. The difference will be the new window if one was opened.

Comment: @batFINGER I'd like to review your canceled answer, to better understand what you tried to do. I am doing an internet search and some tests with blender to see if I can find a solution. I no longer have that code because I haven't saved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer to my question is a simple copy of context. So:

```
ctx = bpy.context.copy()

bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT')

###This is handled with some handlers, but essentially seems to work with a simple context copy

for s in bpy.data.scenes:
     if s == my_scene:
         ctx['window'].scene = s
```

I think this is the answer to my question, but I won't vote for it right now as I could probably cheat in future problems.
For now everything seems to work ok.